# Can I call peerconnection->addStream(stream) in OnAddStream() event

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I try to make peer to peer connection between a server and a client. I send local video stream, through peer connection,
from the client to the server and when once the server received it in onAddStream() event it takes the stream and add it to peer connection with addStream() to send it back to the client, where it came from initially. The source on the server side looks like this:

```
void ServerPeerConnection::OnAddStream(webrtc::MediaStreamInterface* stream)
{
  this->AddStream(stream);
}
```

I know it seems senseless but it's the first step to implement before to go further.

So I'm asking you if it's allowed to the sequence? Should I addStream() before SDP parameters are transferred between the peers or can I call addStream() after. Now doing so I have the following error log:

---

Error(statscollector.cc:192): The SSRC 2128160837 is not associated with a track

Error(statscollector.cc:192): The SSRC 0 is not associated with a track
Transport::ConnectChannels_w: No local description has been set. Will generate o
ne.
Jingle:Channel[audio|1|**]: NULL DTLS identity supplied. Not doing DTLS
Jingle:Channel[audio|2|**]: NULL DTLS identity supplied. Not doing DTLS

Answer (score 0):

You can **attach** the **remote stream** like this:

```
var MediaStream = window.webkitMediaStream || window.MediaStream;

firstPeer.onaddstream = function(remoteSteam) {
      remoteStream = new MediaStream(remoteSteam.audioTracks, remoteSteam.videoTracks);
      otherPeer.addStream(remoteStream);  /* attaching remote stream */
};
```

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/2

Comment: Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: Can I transform stream from LocalMediaStream to MediaStream type?

Comment: Thank you Muaz but this is a browser solution. I want the same in libjingle or any other API that supports webrtc. Here can be found a possible solution which I haven't tried yet. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Km3i7NpnF6U .Actually the method is the same as in your proposal.